# Workflow for baking High Poly UVs to image texture to use on low poly model?

Tags: uv, workflow, normals, texture-baking

Looking at the normal map of this asset. It looks like it was baked with some of the parts Unwrapped at High-Poly and than the low poly model over it. (Seen in the 3 middle circles). Its only an 8 point cylinder but I can count 16 vertices around the edges of the baked normals. So a higher poly models UVs are baked in?

How is this done? I've tried to do this and end up having to have 3 separate models of the same mesh. A low poly model , and mid poly model. And than a high poly model to bake to the mid poly.

After baking is done I still have to use the lower poly model. My problem is the UVs never line up and I end up having to scale them inside the margin bleed. But when I do that the UVs get stretched or shrunk.

What is the process for doing this?

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe it's me but I find it hard to understand, maybe explain what you're trying to do and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: So you bake from High to Low Poly with 'Selected to Active' option. It looks like the active object was a higher poly mesh when it was baked.  The UVs only show an 8 point cylinder (bottom two circles in the middle) when the texture map shows a 16 point cylinder was used when it was baked. 

Was the low poly unwrapped with 'use subdivision surface' on, and than removed after bake? Sorry I know this question is hard to explain. I will upload blend file after work today.

Comment: so maybe rebake but this time give a higher subdivision level to the modifier of the high-poly object?

Comment: I’ll give that a try! Thank you